# Need help to setup a Samba Server

Tags: centos, samba

My friend has a CentOS v7.3 server running on VMWare. It's an old server, so he can't upgrade CentOS (hardware). Hid programmer is still off work and he's asked me to setup his Samba to allow access to the CentOS server from a Windows 7 workstation in a domain.

He also would like to be able to connect to a Windows Workstation from the CentOS server as well.

What I know about Samba is dangerous. He admitted that they never got it to work! I need the money, so it would ne nice if I can get it working.

I copied the Samba script and change the name of Domain etc., Can anyone help please?

```
[global]
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    load printers = no
    domain master = no
    hosts allow = 127. 192.168.0.0/24
    encrypt passwords = yes
    realm = xxxxxxxx.com
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    netbios name = RHServer1
    cups options = raw
    server string = Samba Server Version %v
    password server = ADServer.xxxxxxxx.com
    default = netlogon
    os level = 20
    printcap name = /dev/null
    preferred master = no
    max log size = 5
    domain logons = yes
;   security = user

         # log files split per-machine:
        # enable the following line to debug:
        # log level =3
        # maximum size of 50KB per log file, then rotate:
;   id map config * : backend -tdb

         # Not interested in printers

[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    browseable = yes
    writable = yes
#   valid users = %S
    valid users = DOMAIN\%S

[Web]
    comment = Web Servers
    browseable = yes
    writable = yes
    path = /var/www/
    guest ok = no
#   valid users = %S
    valid users = DOMAIN\%S

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons:
    [netlogon]
    comment = Network Logon Service
    path = /var/lib/samba/netlogon
    guest ok = no
    writable = no

# Un-comment the following to provide a specific roaming profile share.
# The default is to use the user's home directory:
    [Profiles]
    path = /var/lib/samba/profiles
    browseable = no
    guest ok = yes
```

Comment: If you need to just create Windows shares then it should be a straight forward setup and far from dangerous!!!

Comment: Easy if you know how!